# How does Galilean invariance lead to equality of "mass" flux and momentum density?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, galilean-relativity

Let us consider a fluid, with spacetime translation symmetry, and one internal $U(1)$ symmetry. Corresponding to the spatial translation symmetry, we can write down a momentum conservation equation for momentum density $G_i$ as : $\partial_t G_i + \nabla_j(P\delta_{ji} + v_j G_i) = 0$  ;  where $P$ is the Pressure (assuming no dissipation)

Similarly we can write, for a conservation law corresponding to the $U(1)$ symmetry: $\partial_t n + \nabla_j (n_j) = 0$ ; where, $n$ is the "charge" density, and $n_j$ is $j$th component of the charge current.

We can  interpret $\frac{n_j}{n} = v_j$ , where $v$ is the "fluid velocity". This is the same $v$ as appears in the momentum conservation equation, and is the velocity with which the fluid advects conserved quantities.

If we have an isotropic fluid, we know that $G_i = \rho v_i$, (basically, because the only object that transforms under rotations like we expect $G$ to, is $v$, hence the two must be proportional) where we can take $\rho$ to be some arbitrary function (scalar under rotation) of the hydrodynamic variables ; $\rho = \rho(n,|v|...)$ .

Now comes the part I do not understand : Apparently, the requirement that the above equations must be Galilean invariant (ie, must retain their form under Galilean Transforms) forces us to choose $\rho(n,|v|...) = \alpha n$, where $\alpha$ is some constant. That is, not only is the *direction* of $G$  fixed by the direction of $v$, but also, the *magnitude* of $G$ now scales linearly with the magnitude of $v$.

My question is, what goes wrong if we do not assume this? (I can see how this works when we start off with a "fluid" composed of point particles of some "mass", and then invoke the mechanical definition of momentum of a *single* particle to work out the momentum density of the fluid. What I am looking for is a proof using only the fact of Galilean invariance).

**Addendum** : the exchange of comments below made me think where I have seen *any* derivation of conservation of *mass* in the non-relativistic limit. As far as I can see, I can think of two places:

$(1)$ : $\S 133$, *Fluid Mechanics*, Landau (Relativistic Fluid mechanics). Towards the end of this section, Landau makes the following statement : *"The non-relativistic case is that of small velocities...of the internal(microscopic) motion of fluid particles. In passing to this limit it must be borne in mind that relativistic internal energy $e$ includes the rest energy $nmc^2$ of the fluid particles **($m$ being the rest mass of $1$ particle)** "*

$(2)$ Weinberg (I), page 62, where he is discussing how to obtain Galilean Algebra as low velocity limit of Poincare Algebra : *"..For a system of **typical particle mass $m$**, velocity $v$, the momentum operator ... is expected to be $P \approx mv$..."*

I understand $(1)$ a lot better than $(2)$, but what is clear is that in both cases, we have an additional input, that is, a *particle of mass $m$*.

So, I reiterate my question:

*What does this construction of a single particle of mass $m$ have to do with Galilean invariance? (And actually, what IS Galilean invariant about say, Navier Stokes equation ? )*

Comment: Footnote at end of section 49, *fluid mechanics*, Landau

Comment: Are you getting this derivation from any particular text/paper? You reference section 49 of Landau & Lifschitz, but I cannot find this derivation in there.

Comment: @talrefae  Sorry, this was just meant to be a note to self ; as a reminder to think about implications of what is being said there . The footnote says  "It must be borne in mind that, whatever the definitions used, the mass flux density **j** must always be the momentum of a unit volume of fluid ". This is exactly what is assumed for Galilean field theories. Landau seems to take it as a definition. So, yes, you are right, there is no proof there.

Comment: Sure. I am still curious to know where you found the derivation you listed in your main question, as I find this topic pretty interesting.

Comment: @talrefae  Also, $\S 139$ (The equations of superfluid dynamics) also has a discussion of the implications of Galilean relativity. Don't understand it though. Too hung up on the details of super-fluidity (that I do not understand)

Comment: @talrefae : " I am still curious to know where you found the derivation you listed in your main question" : Actually, this question was motivated by https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535376/ . I tried to answer, and I got confused in the process (as you may see from the edits in my answer there).

Comment: And regarding the specific element in my attempted proof that may be confusing (that $G_i = \rho v_i$). I am pretty sure I haven't actually seen this argument used in exactly this context. But Landau uses this argument a lot. I cannot recall off the top of my head, but if you explore the first few sections of Physical Kinetics, currents are set proportional to velocity based on the fact that both must transform the same way under rotations.